# What is meant by the statement: For every real number $C,$ there is a real number $D$ such that $|x| ≥ D ⇒ f(x) ≥ C?$

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is a function on the real number line.

> For every real number $C,$ there is a real number $D$ such that $|x| ≥ D ⇒ f(x) ≥ C?$

I am having a hard time formulating in my head the picture for this statement.

Specifically, I am struggling to understand what is meant by $|x| ≥ D.$ My first thought is that it is always true since I can find a real number $D < 0,$ but I am likely missing the point.

How do I better go about trying to understand this statement?

Comment: What do you not understand?  Consider the function $f(x)=x^2$ for instance.  The claim you are interested is true for that function.  Indeed, $|x|≥\sqrt {|C|}\implies x^2≥|C|≥C$  so, for any given $C$, we can take $D=\sqrt {|C|}$ (just as an example of how the claim works).

Comment: I would say that as $x\to\pm\infty$, $f(x)$ is eventually as large as you’d like.

Comment: The phrase “such that” doesn't refer to just $|x|>D$, it refers to the whole implication “$\ldots \implies \ldots$”. That is, you need to find a $D$ such that the *implication* is true, not a $D$ such that $|x|>D$ is true (which, as you say, would be completely trivial).

Comment: I once read an excellent metaphor to "visualize" that kind of statement : You can imagine that you and I are playing a game. Suppose there is a function $f(x)$. In the game, first you select a real number $C$. Then I select a real number $D$. If you can select a real number $x\in \{t: |t|>D\}$ s.t. $f(x)<C$ then you win, otherwise I win. Can you give some functions that can let you always defeat me in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the function goes up "to positive infinity" in both directions without falling back too often.  If you draw the graph of the function, what it says is  I get to draw a horizontal line at $C$.  You now need to find $D$ so that outside the interval $(-D,D)$ the function is always above the line.  Inside the interval $(-D,D)$ it can do anything.  In lulu's example of $f(x)=x^2$ you could choose $D=\sqrt C$.  You could also choose $D=100 \sqrt C$.  Once you find $D$ that works any larger value will work as well.

Some functions that fail:
$f(x)=100-\frac 1{|x|}$ because if I choose $C=200$ you are stuck
$f(x)=x$ works fine for $x \gt 0$, but fails in the negative direction
$f(x)=\begin {cases} x^2& x \text { not integer}\\ 0& x \text { integer} \end {cases}$ because if I choose $C=1$ there are always points further out than $D$ where $f(x) \lt 1$

Comment: I think I see. So if I have a function where I cannot find some threshold for $|x|$ where the range of function is always greater than the "line" that I draw, the statement fails? And is it good practice to try and write $D$ in terms of $C$ because of how they depend on one another?

Comment: Like limits, usually one does not bother to actually define $D$ in terms of $C$.  Once you are convinced that you could you just say so and go on.

Answer (score 0):

> > For every real number $C,$ there is a real number $D$ such that $|x| ≥ D ⇒ f(x) ≥ C?$
>
> Specifically, I am struggling to understand what is meant by $|x| ≥ D.$ My first thought is that it is always true since I can find a real number $D < 0$

Your suggestion (for example, putting $D=-3$) forces the antecedent $(|x| ≥
D)$ to be true, resulting in the statement $$\text{For every real number }C,\;(\text{True}\implies f(x) ≥ C),$$ that is, $$\text{For every real number }C,\;f(x) ≥ C,$$ which of course is false.

> How do I better go about trying to understand this statement?

The first part of the given statement means that whichever real $C$ you choose, you can *then* find a suitable real $D.$ This means that $D$ is allowed to depend on $C,$ which means that $D$ does not have to be a fixed number but instead vary with $C.$

The given statement contains an implicit universal quantification; in full: $$\forall C{\in}\mathbb R\;\exists D{\in}\mathbb R\; \forall x{\in}\mathbb R\;\big(|x|\ge D\implies f(x) ≥ C\big).$$ It means that no matter how big you choose $C$ to be, $f$'s value is at least $C$ at every point that is sufficiently far from the origin. In other words, as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty,\:f(x)$ approaches $\infty.$

Comment: Okay, I think I am too attached to the implications then. I now see that in this problem, $D$ depends on $C$ rather than the other way around, which is what I am used to doing. So is it a good habit to think about what the implicit universal quantification says?

Comment: How do you mean? What is noteworthy is that the position of `∀x` clarifies that the choice of $x$ depends on the choice of $C$ & $D.$ $\quad$ "*And is it good practice to try and write D in terms of C because of how they depend on one another?*" You can do this (writing something like `D=C^2+1`) if you are given the rule for $f,$ however in general, the positions of the quantifiers already indicates their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with an example. Let $f(x)=x+5$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us say that $x$ is not just some number but rather belongs to the set $[-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty]$. Now what can I say from this?

I can say that $x \geq 1$ and $x\leq -1$, right?

So, I can write this as $|x|\geq 1$ as then $x \geq 1$ and $-x \geq 1$. The latter also implies that $x \leq -1$.

Once we have this clear, let us now come to $f(x)$. If $x \geq 1$, then $x+5 \geq 1+5$, right? Similarly, if $x\leq -1$, then $x+5 \leq -1+5$.

I can also rewrite this as: When $|x|\geq 1$ then $|f(x)|\geq 6$.

Now, let us try to understand this in context to your question.
For every $1 \in \mathbb{R} \; \exists \; 5 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|\geq 5 \implies |x+5|\geq 5+5 \implies |f(x)|\geq 10$.

You can try this for any value in $\mathbb{R}$ and it will always hold true.

This was a very mechanical and probably a bad way to understand something. What is a good way? Let us visualise this.

Take your X-Y coordinate system. Let $f(x)=y$, then let $y_1$ be some value of $y$ which is $C$ here. Following the line $f(x)$, we can find a corresponding $x$. Note that, from this $x$, no matter how much right or left you move, you will always end up finding a point on the line corresponding to your positive $x$ which extends to infinity and a point corresponding to the negative value of $x$, which extends to $-\infty$.

To illustrate this better, recall our example of $f(x)=x+5$, when $|x|\geq 1$. Now, see this graph:[image] You will see that from $x=1$ to $\infty$ and from $-\infty$ to $x=-1$, for every value of $y$, we have an $x$ such that whenever $x$ is in its domain, $y$ is also in its domain, or rather, when $x$ is bounded, $y$ is also bounded.

Hence proved!

Also note that this cannot be an $\iff$ case. The reason is that if your $f(x)\geq 6$ say, then you cannot say necessarily that you $x$ will be $\geq 6-5=1$ because, you might have values of $x$ such as $1$, for which we have some function $g(x)=x+1$. That is, since you do not know the entire domain of $x$, you cannot say with certainity for values of $x$ might be as $f(x)$ is the dependent variable and not $x$. So, I might have multiple functions on some set of $x$ values but they may all have their domains as a subset of this set, hence, predicting values of $x$ using a particular function will never return its true range or the complete set of all $x$ values.

Comment: I see that your example works with $|f(x)|$ where $f(x) = x + 5$, but wouldn't if fail if you only consider $f(x)$?

Comment: can you please elaborate? The proposition you mentioned clearly says, that if $|x|>D$ then |f(x)>C| and not vice versa. So if you take just $x\geq 3$, say then $f(x)=x+5\geq 8$ and that is true. Since we saw before that range of $f(x)$ is from $6$ to $\infty$ for $x$ positive.